# C - I am trying to use fprintf in a recursive function but it is only printing minimum lines

Tags: c, file, recursion, printf

I am using fprintf in the recursive c function below to print to a file, although the only exact output to the file I am seeing is:

- question: Does it fly?
- This is a test

I am confused because when I use printf, the output is fine on standard output. It is printing a tree and should be much longer.

I have tried to use a few ways to debug, but I cannot think what it could be anymore.

```
void treePrint(struct node *rootNodePointer)
{

 FILE *fp;

 fp = fopen("Output.txt", "w");// "w" means that we are going to write on this file

 if (fp == NULL)
 {
   printf("Error opening file!\n");
   exit(1);
 }

 if(rootNodePointer != NULL)
 {
   if(strcmp(rootNodePointer -> object, "question") == 0)
   {
     fprintf(fp, "question: %s\n", rootNodePointer -> value);
     fprintf(fp, "this is a test");

     printf("question: %s\n", rootNodePointer -> value);
     treePrint(rootNodePointer -> left);
     treePrint(rootNodePointer -> right);
   }  

   else if(strcmp(rootNodePointer -> object, "object") == 0)
   {
     fprintf(fp, "object %s\n", rootNodePointer -> value);
     printf("object: %s", rootNodePointer -> value);

   }

 }

  else
  {
    printf("Error!");
    exit(1);
  }

 printf("\n");
 fclose(fp);
}//treePrint

*** Error in `Pangolins': double free or corruption (top):         0x000000000128b2e0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7d023)[0x7eff65272023]
/lib64/libc.so.6(fclose+0x155)[0x7eff6525fff5]
Pangolins[0x400a9a]
Pangolins[0x400a1a]
Pangolins[0x400a03]
Pangolins[0x401131]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7eff65216b15]
Pangolins[0x4007c9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 00:2c 2360081
```

Answer (score 3):

You are [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen)-ing the same file in a recursive function (without append mode)  - and `fclose`-ing the same handle near the end of that recursive body. It will be overwritten at every call.

You should `fopen` the file once (e.g. in `main`) outside of that recursive function, and pass that  `FILE*` handle to your recursive function. Don't forget to test against failure of that `fopen`. So your recursive function should be declared as:

```
void treePrint(FILE*fp, struct node *NodePointer);
```

and the body of `treePrint` should not contain any call to `fopen` or `fclose`.

And you'll better use [`fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) inside your recursive function (at least during the debugging phase) since stdio is buffered.

Don't forget to call `fclose`, probably in the same outside function (e.g. `main`) doing the `fopen`.

As a rule of thumb, an opened `FILE*` handle contains some [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) (at least on Unix) so is quite an expensive resource. On 1980s Unix systems you could have only a few dozens of file descriptors per [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). On current Linux system you might be allowed to have a thousand of them (but you can limit them using [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)).

At last, compile your code with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), improve it to get no warnings, and **[use](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) the debugger `gdb`**.

Your error `double free or corruption` is [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) related, so use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to hunt that bug. You could also use the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) by [passing also](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) `-fsanitize=address` to `gcc`.

Comment: I just added how that function should be declared. Isn't that enough for you?

Comment: Yes I have done that although I am getting a very unusual error, I have put it above below my code. Thanks.

Comment: Please take the habit of compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and learn to use the debugger